# Problemas ao converter variavel javascript para transferir em uma rota do Laravel

Tags: php, javascript, laravel

Estou com problemas de passar uma variável de JavaScript para dentro de uma rota do Laravel. Para tal, estou utilizando uma requisição AJAX. O codigo que estou utilizando está logo abaixo:

```
            $.ajax({
                url: 'rota/emails/'+p.id,
                type: "GET",
                data : {"_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                  if(data){ 
                    $.each(data, function(key, value){
                      $('#received-emails').append('<div class="text-center">' + value.email+ '</div><a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{route("rota.delete", '+value.id+')}}"><span class="fa fa-user-times"></span></a>'); //o problema esta nesta linha
                    });

                  }
                }
              });
```

No uso do `id` `#received-emails`, eu adiciono as divs com o respectivo HTML mostrado acima. O `value.email` funciona corretamente, ja o `value.id` não. No meu *controller*, o `id` é recebido como `+value.id+` e não como o respectivo `id` que está sendo adquirido pelo AJAX.

A príncipio estou tentando criar um simples botão que ao clicar nele, seja redirecionado para uma rota do *Laravel* onde esta a funcionalidade de excluir. Como o exemplo abaixo:

```
<a href="{{route('rota.delete', id)}}"></a>
```

Eu acabei construindo algo como isso dentro do *append*:

```
'<a class="btn btn-danger" href="{{route("rota.delete", '+value.id+')}}"><span class="fa fa-user-times"></span></a>'
```

Qual pode ser a solução para esse problema?

Comment: Muda pra `href="{{route("rota.delete", value.id)}}"`

Comment: aparece um erro como:   Use of undefined constant value - assumed 'value' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso não é possível pois o Laravel funciona no back-end.
O Blade Template do Laravel compila a view e irá executar a função route() e retornar o a url da rota antes mesmo de gerar o HTML que será enviado para o cliente. ou seja, ele vai compilar a função route() antes de executar qualquer javascript.
Sendo assim isso nao é possível. :(
Porém eu conheço algumas "gambiarras" que resolvem isso.

Em vez de colocar

```
route("rota.delete", 'value.id')
```

Use

```
var url = "{{ route('rota.delete', ['id' => ':id']) }}"; // isso vai compilar o blade com o id sendo uma string ":id" e, no javascript, atribuir ela a uma variável .

url = url.replace(":id", value.id); // isso vai corrigir a string gerada com o id correto.

console.log(url); // isso vai mostrar a url gerada. Aí a lógica é com você.
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu o meu problema